# Check existing routes in Hapi proxy handlers

Tags: proxy, legacy, hapi.js

Scenario: I have an existing legacy application which has lots of routes. I am developing HAPI API which has all new routes. I will convert all existing routes into hapi over time. If incoming route does not match with existing HAPI routes, I will forward those into legacy system.

How can i check my all current hapi routes for incoming route request before forwarding it to other legacy system? Any kind of example, advice will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for the [h2o2](https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2) plugin. It's a proxy handler plugin for hapi.

Register the plugin:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.register({
    register: require('h2o2')
}, function (err) {

    if (err) {
        console.log('Failed to load h2o2');
    }

    server.start(function (err) {

        console.log('Server started at: ' + server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

Create a hapi route that will forward requests to another:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: {
        proxy: {
            uri: 'https://some.upstream.service.com/that/has?what=you&want=todo'
        }
    }
});
```

You can also add more [complicated route handling](https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2#using-the-mapuri-and-onresponse-options) if you need it. Check out the documentation.